# How can I download a photo from my Canon 6D and open in Lightroom for Android?

Tags: lightroom, canon-6d, mobile

How can download a photo over WiFi from my Canon 6D and edit the RAW file in [Adobe Lightroom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.lrmobile) for Android?

I currently am able to download a JPEG from my Canon 6D connecting with [Canon Camera Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.canon.ic.cameraconnect) app on Android over WiFi. But I don't seem to be able to download the RAW file with Camera Connect app.

Answer (score 2):

[Canon Camera Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.canon.ic.cameraconnect) does not list support for raw Canon .CR2 files. This is probably due to the much larger size of raw files versus compressed JPEG files.

Some Canon cameras, including the EOS 6D, have the ability to do some raw processing in camera using the camera's LCD screen. You could do things such as color temperature in camera before saving as a jpeg and transferring to your android device via Canon Camera Connect.

The [EOS 6D Instruction Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300009238/03/eos6d-im4-en.pdf) has an entire chapter devoted to in-camera post-processing of images that begins on page 271. It lists the options available for raw images:

- Brightness. Up to +/- 1 stop in 1/3 stop increments.
- White Balance. You can select a preset WB (Cloudy, Shade, etc.) or select a color temperature (5200K, 6400K, etc.). Unfortunately, you can't change WB correction from the "as shot" selected setting. To adjust the green←→magenta axis, you must use the 'Color Tone' adjustment within the 'Picture Style' section.
- Picture Style. You can select a Picture Style and adjust the parameters within each Picture Style: Sharpness, Contrast, Saturation, and Color Tone.
- Auto Lighting Optimizer. Select between 'Off', 'Low', 'Standard', or 'High'.
- High ISO Speed Noise reduction. Choose between:  'Off', 'Low', 'Standard', or 'High'.
- Image Quality. Select the resolution and compression settings for jpeg output. The choices will be the same as those in the camera's menu for selecting how to output images shot straight to jpeg.
- Color Space. sRGB or Adobe RGB. Note that the camera's LCD will not display Adobe RGB correctly, so that selection should be made following all other adjustments.
- Peripheral Illumination correction. 'On' or 'Off' if the correction profile for the lens used has been stored in the camera. A few lenses are included in the factory settings. Other profiles for additional Canon lenses can be added to the camera via 'EOS Utility'.
- Distortion Correction. 'On' or 'Off' if the correction profile for the lens used has been stored in the camera. A few lenses are included in the factory settings. Other profiles for additional Canon lenses can be added to the camera via 'EOS Utility'.
- Chromatic Aberration Correction. 'On' or 'Off' if the correction profile for the lens used has been stored in the camera. A few lenses are included in the factory settings. Other profiles for additional Canon lenses can be added to the camera via 'EOS Utility'.

You can also resize jpeg images from the available jpeg size options. They're the same as the size options from the camera's menu for setting jpeg output size before taking an image. You can only resize a jpeg image to a smaller size option.